# How to set properties from Advanced Editor such as FastParse using BIML

Tags: ssis, biml

I'm creating SSIS packages using BIML, all works well, however I'm not able to find a way to set the properties from the Advanced Editor such as Fast Parse.

I want to do the following for a Date field.

> 1.Add a Data Conversion Data Flow Component. 
>   2.Right click, Show Advanced Editor... 
>   3.Goto Input and Output Properties 
>   4.Expand Data Conversion Output and click on the date column 
>   5.Set FastParse to True in the Custom Properties

This is straight forward with in SSIS package, how the same can be achieved using BIML.

Following is the sample BIML I use to generate the date field.

> ```
>                            <DataConversion Name="DC Data Conversion">
>                                 <Columns>
>                                     <Column SourceColumn="OrderDate" TargetColumn="DC_Order_Date" DataType="Date"  />
>                                 </Columns>
>                                 <ErrorHandling ErrorRowDisposition="RedirectRow" TruncationRowDisposition ="RedirectRow" />
>                             </DataConversion>
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [BIML Documentation](https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Language/Element/AstDataConversionColumnNode), you should use `FastParse` property of proper `Column` node, like

```
<Columns>  
     <Column SourceColumn="OrderDate" TargetColumn="DC_Order_Date" DataType="Date" FastParse="true" />  
</Columns>
```

to configure `FastParse` column property of DataType Conversion transformation.